# Two BlackBerry Webworks packagers in the same folder location

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

So we develop apps for Blackberry OS7 & earlier as well as of recently, apps for BB10. The problem is that BB OS7 uses a different WebWorks SDK as opposed to BB10 & yet I am to install them both in the same directory as per the documentation.

The problem comes in when attempting to sign since the executable files for both SDK's have the same name.

Hence when I attempt to sign my BB 7 app using "bbwp" it throws an error. The error output is "Cannot Sign Application - failed to find signing key file: author.p12". This is obviously the BB10 "bbwp" executable file that's running.This is because both "bbwp" executable files are in the same location and both are named "bbwp".

How does one get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! And quite a simple solution too!

All I did was to give a different folder name to one of the SDK's. When I ran the command to sign, I simply navigated to the new folder name, called the bbwp.exe and ran it against my project!